# How can I style a Dash Core Component directly in the app?

Tags: plotly-dash

I know I can style a DCC by wrapping it in a Div, but that's extra code.

I tried this:

```
dcc.Slider(id='slider', min=0, max=50, style=dict(width='50%'))
```

and I got:

```
TypeError: The `dash_core_components.Slider` component (version 1.10.2) with the ID "slider" received an unexpected keyword argument: `style`
```

Is there a way to avoid extra code of wrapping DCC in a Div and style it directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all Dash components have the `style` prop. They pretty much all have `className`, so you could assign that and update your `.css` file to assign styles to that class - or even to the ID you use - though I realize that isn't directly in the app as you mentioned.

It's not so bad, though, if you have to wrap things in divs. They work well to get the job done, and I find they're easy to manage, while some other components can be trickier.

Comment: Wow, for whatever reason I did not realize or bothered to check that an ID I assign to a DCC is automatically assigned to an artificially created Div that wraps this DCC. So I totally agree that targeting it with an external CSS will reduce the amount of code, especially repetitive code.

Comment: Speaking about `className`, so I just do `dcc.Slider(id='slider', min=0, max=50, className='slider')` ?

Comment: That would work. Then, in your CSS file, you'd do `.slider { }` with whatever styles.